# I don't understand why is this loop not infinite

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

To stop the loop `foundAtPosition` needs to be equal to `-1` how is that ?

```
var myString = "Welcome to Wrox books. ";
myString = myString + "The Wrox website is www.wrox.com. ";
myString = myString + "Visit the Wrox website today. Thanks for buying Wrox";
var foundAtPosition = 0;
var wroxCount = 0;
while (foundAtPosition != -1) {
    foundAtPosition = myString.indexOf("Wrox", foundAtPosition);
    if (foundAtPosition != -1) {
        wroxCount++;
        foundAtPosition++;
    }
}
document.write("There are " + wroxCount + " occurrences of the word Wrox");
```

Comment: `indexOf` method returns -1 when no match is found.

Comment: indexOf returns -1 if the item is not found. so the loop will end.

Comment: Well, until not found the word

Comment: Not sure I understand the reasoning of the question. Why do you expect it to be infinite?

Comment: i didnt know that indexOf return -1 when no match found

Comment: Oh, so now I understand your question :) So for next time, I suggest to go back to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and make sure you know what the function returns (Perhaps you thought it will return 0, or false?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key relies on these two lines

```
- This line
|
v
foundAtPosition = myString.indexOf("Wrox", foundAtPosition);

if (foundAtPosition != -1) {
    wroxCount++;
    foundAtPosition++; <- And this line
}
```

The algorithm is moving through the positions of your String:

**For example:**

```
var phrase = "The Wrox website is www.wrox.com." <- Iteration [1]
                  ^
                  |_ First occurence at position [4] -> foundAtPosition++ = 5 -> wroxCount = 1


"The Wrox website is www.wrox.com." <- Iteration [2] -> The algorithm won't find the word because the `indexOf` function finds the index from position [5] til `phrase.length`.
                                  ^
                                  |_ No more occurences, therefore, foundAtPosition = -1
```

**Result:** `wroxCount === 1`

## Resource

- [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Answer (score 1):

> i don't understand why is this loop not infinit

It will be infinite if you don't pass the second parameter `foundAtPosition`

```
foundAtPosition = myString.indexOf("Wrox", foundAtPosition);
```

But since you passed this parameter, second time onwards it will look from (after this `foundAtPosition` index) and eventually it will have `-1`

Answer (score 0):

`while` loop is executing **while** is condition evaluated as **true**. `indexOf` returns index **-1** when given word is not found in string.